# React Dynamic Router / works in dev mode but not in build mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

`main.jsx`:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path='/'>
      <Route index element={<App />} />
      <Route path="blog/:id" element={<BlogArticle />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>   
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

My link to `BlockArticle` looks like this:

```
<Link to={`/blog/id=${blog.id}\`} reloadDocument={true}>
```

I map over the blog array and add the ID to the link

and in `BlockArticle` I catch the ID:

```js
const lastField = document.location.pathname.split("=");

return <div key={blog.id}>
    { blog.id == lastField[1] ? ... : ... }
```

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.14.1"
```

and in dev mode everything works, but if I build and upload the project I get (only when I try to open some of the `BlogArticles`) a "Server Error 404 Page Not Found" appears.

I'm completely new to React, maybe it's very simple.
But after half day of googling I'm still lost.

Comment: Are you using a builtd tool like Webpack, Vite, or CRA? And how are you serving the production build of your SPA?

Comment: How are you hosting the site? Which HTTP server are you using?

Comment: i'm using Vite. and i host the site on "onyxhosting.de"

Comment: This isn't a React app or `react-router-dom` issue. Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see if there's a relevant section for the hosting service/server environment for where/how you are deploying your app to. The basic gist is that you need to return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. Once the app is correctly served up to clients the React app should mount and routing internally working as expected.

Comment: If you’re using Apache HTTP Server, you need to create a .htaccess file in the public folder that looks like this:

    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]  this works! now everthing works, like it should. thanks the deployment docs link and the help :)